# C++ Why is it calling the function with reference

Tags: c++

say i have the following C++ class.

```
class C
{
   int foo() const;
   int & foo();
};
```

and i just call `myC.foo()`, i can see using the debugger that it calls the one with the reference.

why?

thanks!

Comment: You don't think showing the definition of `myC` might be pertinent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's likely because `myC` is a non-const value and hence the compiler is prefering the non-const method.  The `const` method will only be preferred when accessed from a `const` value.  For example

```
C value1;
value1.foo();  // int& foo();
const C value2;
value2.foo();  // int foo() const;
```

**EDIT**

Also, as Oli pointed out, overload resolution in C++ is not affected by the return type of the method.  So it won't pick one of these signatures over the other based on the way in which the value is used.

Comment: +1: Indeed.  Also worth mentioning that overload resolution is not affected by return type?

Answer (score 3):

Because `myC` must have not been an const obj.

C++ allows functions to be overloaded on the basis of the `const` keyword.

If a const object of the class is created only const member functions can be called through that object because they guarantee that they wont modify the state of the object.

a non const object can call both const as well as non const member functions but compilers gives preference to non const member functions over const member functions and hence the behavior in your case.